# How to make crud app in React Js and Sqlite database or any other without backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, desktop-application

I am working on a project where I want to create a offline application. We are ready to use react js and integrate it to electron app. We are trying since a week that how can we do this using react and sqlite. It can be done using express js but when we build the electron together and make exe file it does not work.

If anyone knows how to do this or is there any alternative then please help us to figure it out.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Do you have any **specific** question about this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work with expressjs, refer to the following documentations.

> - [Medium: Electron JS + React JS + Express JS](https://medium.com/@keshavagrawal/electron-js-react-js-express-js-b0fb2aa8233f)
> - [Github: Getting Started with Electron,React,Express App](https://github.com/miloman23/ReactJS-ElectronJS-ExpressJS-App)

Also check out [Stackoverflow: How to connect to a sqlite db from a React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56583738/how-to-connect-to-a-sqlite-db-from-a-react-app) to integrate sqllite into your React App using sqljs.

Alternatively, why not consider using local storage since you can do without expressjs.

For me, the major reason one needs a server side is to centralize your application into one secure command center for all its users. The server side gives you the opportunity to securely communicate with your database thereby aggregating data from all the application users.

If this is your use case, then its best you serve your expressjs app from a host and communicate with your backend apps through api.
(Note at development level: you can serve your express app remotely)

If this is not your use case then just stick to using localhost. ***Whats the point an express app if its served at the front end?***

**UPDATED:**

Check out the following documentation to find what suits you:

> - [Dev.to: Using NedDB](https://dev.to/ctxhou/local-data-storage-for-electron-2h4p)
> - [Electron Store](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-store)
> - [Electron Data Holder](https://github.com/gugocharade/electron-data-holder#readme)
> - [Persisting Data Using Electron Settings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/persisting-data-in-electronjs/)
> - [Stackoverflow: Electron store data locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72020439/electron-store-data-locally-without-localstorage)